# How to stop a script within another script

Tags: shell-script, kill, pkill

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04, using a terminal emulator.

I have two scripts: `a.sh` and `b.sh`. 
`a.sh` calls `b.sh`.

`a.sh`

```
echo "a is running"
sleep 5s
bash b.sh
sleep 5s
echo "a is still running"
```

`b.sh`

```
echo "b is now running"
sleep 1000s
echo "Bananas"
```

Is there a way to run `a.sh`, stop `b.sh` before it completes (before it prints Bananas) and let `a.sh` run to completion and print "a is still running"?

I have tried putting `pkill -f b.sh` inside `a.sh`, but both `a.sh` and `b.sh` stop before `a.sh` completes.

Comment: What happened when you tried `pkill -f b.sh` within the `a.sh` script?

Comment: What @Kusalananda says

Comment: Depending on platform, I either get your scripts working just fine, or failing because `b.sh` has already finished before the `pkill` line runs. I don't really think either of those outcomes is wrong, but it does mean that what works is going to depend on which platform you're targeting. That said, I don't think I understand what you're trying to do or trying to test and I suspect that your test script doesn't really represent what you want.

Comment: It would be helpful to [edit] in the message you get/a transcript of you running the commands.

Comment: Interesting puzzle that you created!

Comment: Puzzle indeed interesting but what would be a practical application ? More importantly, what's the actual issue to solve ?

Answer (score 5):

At one point, you were close to what you seem to want.

`a.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "a.sh running"
sleep 10s
(sleep 10s; pkill -f b.sh) &
bash b.sh
sleep 10s
pkill -f b.sh
echo "a.sh still running"
```

`b.sh`    *(same as your version)*

```
echo "b is now running"
sleep 1000s
echo "Bananas"
```

The `(sleep 10s; pkill -f b.sh) &` line in `a.sh`
creates a subshell that sleeps for ten seconds and then kills `b.sh`. 
It then puts that subshell into the background,
so `a.sh` can keep running. 
`a.sh` then runs `b.sh`, which runs `sleep 1000s`. 
Ten seconds later, the `sleep 10s` in the subshell finishes,
and it (the subshell) runs `pkill -f b.sh`, killing the `b.sh` process. 
`a.sh` then resumes running. 
The second `pkill -f b.sh` does nothing,
since the `b.sh` process is already terminated.

This is what happens when it runs:

```
$ ./a.sh
a.sh running                                              # immediately
b is now running                                          # about 10 seconds after the above
./a.sh: line 6: 13684 Terminated            bash b.sh     # about 10 seconds after the above
a.sh still running                                        # about 10 seconds after the above
$                                                         # immediately after the above
```

This has the advantage that `a.sh` can resume running immediately
if `b.sh` finishes quickly. 
Only if `b.sh` runs for more than 10 seconds does the `pkill` kick in. 
In the other answer, `a.sh` has to sit idle
while the `sleep` before the `pkill` takes up time,
even if `b.sh` has already wrapped up.

---

[Another user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/265604/isaac) posted [a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/421707/80216#comment758782_421744) (now deleted) saying

> I get
>
> ```
> ./a.sh
> a.sh running
> b is now running
> Terminated
> ```
>
> not what you report. Any idea?

## It was a dark and stormy night.  Suddenly, a shot rang out!

<sup>—[It Was a Dark and Stormy Night, Snoopy](https://www.goodreads.com/work/quotes/110405-it-was-a-dark-and-stormy-night-snoopy)
by Charles M. Schulz</sup>

The argument to `pgrep` and `pkill` is a regular expression;
specifically, an Extended Regular Expression<sup>1</sup>. 
Try running `cat` and `cut` simultaneously<sup>2</sup>. 
Then do `pgrep c.t` — it will list two PIDs,
and you can confirm with `ps` that they are `cat` and `cut`.

If you had done ***exactly*** what I said,
you really should have gotten the same results I did. 
But I’m willing to wager 42 Zorkmids that you did something different. 
You either:

1. Began `a.sh` with `#!/bin/bash` as a she-bang (first line)
   instead of `#!/bin/sh`, or
2. Ran `a.sh` with `bash a.sh` instead of `./a.sh`.

#### Suddenly, a shot rang out!

`b.sh` is a regular expression that matches `b`
followed by any character followed by `sh`. 
It matches itself (`b.sh`),
and also things like `b!sh`, `b~sh`, `b&sh`, `b7sh`, and `bush`. 
And … … (wait for it) … … it also matches `bash`!

So `pkill -f b.sh` kills all bash processes,
and also any others that have `b.sh` in their names. 
When I ran what I ran, my login shell
(which is at least partially immune to `pkill`) was bash,
but `a.sh` was running under `/bin/sh`
(but `b.sh` was running under `bash`). 
The `pkill -f b.sh` command killed the `bash b.sh` process
because it contained ***both*** `bash` and `b.sh`. 
But the `/bin/sh` that was running `a.sh` was unaffected.

Assuming you ran it the way I believe you ran it
(either of the two alternatives),
*all* the script processes were running `bash`. 
And so the `pkill -f b.sh` command killed *all* the script processes.

Change `pkill -f b.sh` to `pkill -f 'b\.sh'`
(escaping the dot so it matches *only* a dot, and not any character),
and you should get the right results.
________
<sup>1</sup> [pgrep(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pgrep.1.html)
<sup>2</sup> If you have two terminals (shell windows),
run `cat | cut -f1` (with input from the terminal) in one of them,
and the `p`-commands in the other. 
If you have only one terminal,
run `sleep 42 | cat | cut -f1 &`
(without the `sleep`, the pipeline would collapse immediately),
and then run `p`-commands in the same window.

Answer (score 3):

The line:

```
bash b.sh
```

will wait for the `b.sh` script to finish, there is no way to do anything in the script before `b.sh` ends because the `a.sh` does not have the control.

To have the `b.sh` script go to background and give control back to `a.sh` is to use a like similar to:

```
bash b.sh &
```

That returns the control to `a.sh` immediately and we can have this kind of script:

```
#!/bin/bash 

echo "a is running"
sleep 1s
bash b.sh &
sleep 2
pkill -f 'b\.sh'
sleep 1s
echo "a is still running"
```

While script `b.sh` keeps being:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "b is now running"
sleep 1000s
echo "Bananas"
```

On execution you will get:

```
$ ./a.sh
a is running
b is now running
./a.sh: line 7:  8424 Terminated              bash b.sh
a is still running
```

To avoid the "Job control message" use a sub-shell, change `bash b.sh &` to:

```
(bash b.sh &)
```

And, on execution, you will get:

```
$ ./a.sh
a is running
b is now running
a is still running
```

---

## Edit:

The problem with a 'Terminated' response you report is that the pkill command you posted `pkill -f b.sh` is using the argument as a regex. That regex match `b` followed by any character `.` followed by `sh`. That match the name 'bash' which is the program started to run also `a.sh`, that explain why `a.sh` is being terminated. Change the pkill command to:

```
pkill -f 'b\.sh'
```

to ensure that the matched regex is a plain string 'b.sh'.

You can see the processes that the pkill would match by placing this:

```
ps -f -o pid,cmd,args |grep 'b.sh'
```

just before the pkill.

Change it to `grep 'b\.sh'` to find out that it actually match only one pid.

Comment: Thanks - but it didn't work - I got 'Terminated' after 'b is now running' - b.sh must have stopped - a.sh seemed to stop before completion - never got 'a is still running' - same thing that happened with my above scripts. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Added an edit to explain why you get a `Terminated`: quote `'b\.sh'` to avoid this *pattern* to match `bash`. @speld_rwong

Answer (score 0):

Your `a.sh` script must run the `b.sh` script as a background job to be able to terminate it prematurely.

Since `b.sh` is run as a background job, you have access to its process ID (PID), which means you may use `kill` to signal it.  This is safer than using `pkill` which will potentially signal other processes that matches the pattern that you're giving to it.

You could do the following in `a.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "A: I'm alive!"
./b.sh & bpid=$!

echo 'A: Sleeping for a short while'
sleep 2

echo 'A: Signalling B'
kill "$bpid"

echo "A: I'm done here"
```

The `$!` will expand to the PID of the most recently started background task.

Example of `b.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "B: I'm alive!"

echo 'B: Sleeping for longer than A does'
sleep 10

echo "B: I'm done here"
```

Running it:

```
$ ./a.sh
A: I'm alive!
A: Sleeping for a short while
B: I'm alive!
B: Sleeping for longer than A does
A: Signalling B
A: I'm done here
```

Note that `b.sh` may not actually terminate until its `sleep` call is done. This is the case with `bash`, `dash`, `zsh` and `pdksh`, but not with `ksh93` (with which `b.sh` terminates immediately).

Answer (score -1):

I have used below method. Added one extra line in b.sh which makes to work as per requirement

script a.sh will be the same

```
script a.sh

echo "a is running"
sleep 5s
bash b.sh
sleep 5s
echo "a is still running"
```

=====================================================

```
script b.sh

echo "b is now running"
sleep 20s

exit
```

==>exit command will come out of the script

```
echo "Bananas"
```

output

```
   a is running
b is now running
a is still running
```

Comment: You still are required to quote the regex to grep: `| grep -i 'b\.sh' |` or you run the risk of calling kill on a bash shell.

Comment: So, rather than having `a.sh` stop `b.sh`, as the OP seems to want, you propose having `b.sh` stop itself? You know there’s a much shorter command that does something similar: ``exit``.  Why not just put an `exit` command in the middle of `b.sh`?